# Using regex with split() just to get full name within string

Tags: typescript

**I have this string :**

```
var author = "Tom Smith, Will Hughes, Adonis Young and Tyrek Hill";
```

**And this is the function getNumOfAuthor :**

```
function getNumOfAuthor(m_name:string) {
    const regex = /\s*(?:,|$)\s*/;
    var str = m_name.split(regex);
    alert(str.length);
    alert(str);
    if (str.length == 1) {
      num_of_author = 1;
    }
    else if (str.length > 1) {
      num_of_author = str.length;
    }

    return num_of_author;
  }
```

I want to use the `split()` method so that the full names are separated into elements in string array using regex as the split delimiter

Does anyone know what the regex would be? I can get comma working, but I can't seem to figure out how to have multiple punctuation and specific phrases working alongside it

Comment: I don't know about TypeScript, but can you just substitute ' and ' for a comma and split that?  Snippet -> `author.replace(/\sand\s/, ', ').split(/(?:,\s?)/)`  My output from your `author` variable is: `["Tom Smith", "Will Hughes", "Adonis Young", "Tyrek Hill"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Just count the number of `,` and `and` and add one.
2. Split by `,` and `and` and count the length of the array.

```js
var author = "Tom Smith, Will Hughes, Adonis Young and Tyrek Hill"

// First suggestion.
let authorCount = author.match(/(, )|( and )/).length + 1;
console.log("num of authors", authorCount);

// Second suggestion.
let authors = author.split(/, | and /)
console.log(authors, authors.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some scary regex for you to use.

```js
const author = "Tom Smith, Will Hughes, Adonis Young and Tyrek Hill";

const regex = /,\s|and\s|(?<name>\w+\s\w+)/g

const result = [...author.matchAll(regex)]
  .map(pr => pr.groups || {
    name: null
  })
  .filter(pr => pr.name)
  .map(pr => pr.name)

console.log(result);
```